# Call function only once Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a radio button where the user can select either Metric or Imperial units.
The following code is the event handler:

```
var metricRadio = document.getElementById("metric");
var imperialRadio = document.getElementById("imperial");

metricRadio.addEventListener("click", toMetric, false);

imperialRadio.addEventListener("click", toImperial, false);
```

When the user clicks the Metric radio button the function `toMetric` is called. In the function `toMetric` I convert what the user entered in Imperial to Metric and I update the input boxes with the Metric values. The problem is that if Metric is selected and he clicks the Metric radio button again the function `toMetric` is called again. How can I prevent calling the `toMetric` function when the Metric radio button is selected.

You can test what I mean here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/43xqq/2/)

Just enter 3 values and click the Metric or Imperial radio button more than once.

Comment: You want to disable the metric handler when you are displaying metric and disable the imperial handler when you are displaying metric?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

Look at this: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/siva_hari/aYxph/).

I used "change" instead of "click":

```
metricRadio.addEventListener("change", toMetric, false);

imperialRadio.addEventListener("change", toImperial, false);
```

Comment: An alternative is to have a single handler for the div above it and detect which one is active. http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/aYxph/2/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to call a function only once (which you can do setting a variable), you should add a variable containing the current state (metric or imperial) and in your function you test the current state with an if condition

Comment: Here's an implementation of what you are suggesting http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/43xqq/3/ However, Siva's idea seems to be the best choice because you don't have to track state yourself

Comment: In fact you don't need to add a variable, you can check the status of the checkbox. See update : http://jsfiddle.net/43xqq/5/

Comment: That doesn't work because the `checked` state already changed by the time your handler is called (I tried that too) Try clicking metric multiple times